# Enabling PDF417 Decoding in Zxing

Tags: java, ant, computer-vision, zxing, pdf417

I am trying to get [PDF417](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) barcode reading to be enabled in [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) (Zebra Crossing). I did a pull from the [github repo](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and built the library according to the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted). The ant build output [seems to indicate](https://gist.github.com/4218363) that the PDF417 submodule is being built. I tried to test everything according to the wiki using [these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOR2y.jpg) but I get a "no barcode found" error.

```
kscottz@kscottz-laptop:~/barcode/zxing$  java -cp javase/javase.jar:core/core.jar com.google.zxing.client.j2se.CommandLineRunner Sample_PDF417.png 
file:/home/kscottz/barcode/zxing/Sample_PDF417.png: No barcode found
kscottz@kscottz-laptop:~/barcode/zxing$  java -cp javase/javase.jar:core/core.jar com.google.zxing.client.j2se.CommandLineRunner bc.png 
file:/home/kscottz/barcode/zxing/bc.png: No barcode found
kscottz@kscottz-laptop:~/barcode/zxing$  java -cp javase/javase.jar:core/core.jar com.google.zxing.client.j2se.CommandLineRunner sanitycheck.jpg 
file:/home/kscottz/barcode/zxing/sanitycheck.jpg (format: QR_CODE, type: TEXT):
Raw result:
<-- SNIP -->
```

What gives? Am I missing a flag to enable PDF417? Where would one look to set these sorts of configuration options? I am regularly a Python/C/C++ developer so I may be missing something pretty basic.

Comment: Have you tried [PDF417.mobi SDK](https://github.com/PDF417)? It works, it's quite easy to integrate and it's free for non-commercial apps. Disclaimer: I work for the developer of PDF417.mobi

Answer (score 1):

Try `--try_harder`, otherwise it's in the mode suitable for mobile devices, instead of using more CPU to scan the image more. `--pure_barcode` will probably work too since these are synthetic images.

In general. These don't seem to decode though. I can't access the first image, and the second isn't found even in the online decoder (which you can always use as a check):  http://zxing.elasticbeanstalk.com/w/decode.jspx

I don't know why since I presume it's valid. You can run through the debugger to see exactly what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran the ZXing test script on the test barcodes and they do pass, so I am going to assume it is enabled. It appears that when zxing says alpha they really mean alpha. =(

Comment: The test script is not the same as the CommandLineRunner program, and while all code is built, it is not necessarily enabled. But PDF417 is turned on for CommandLineRunner. I don't know what images you're decoding, but people contributed a bunch of changes to PDF417 in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to detect only PDF417 barcode using ZXING library, you need to pass in the hints asking ZXING to only look for PDF417 type.

try below,

```
 hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.PDF_417));
```

Checkout the below example,

```
LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<>(DecodeHintType.class);

        hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.PDF_417));
        //hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, true);
        Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap, hints);
```